# Hyper-V VM Static IP - 2 IP Addresses

Tags: network-adapter, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to configure a server with virtual machines on Windows Server 2012, after finishing the installation of windows in the VM, I try to configure the IP as static, but a second address is assigned to the VM, which gets two addresses being the configured manually the second.

The configuration looks like this:

- Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
- Description: Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
- Physical Address: 00-15-5D-FE-0C-01
- DHCP Enabled: No
- **Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 169.254.243.109**
- **IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0**
- **Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 192.168.254.30**
- **IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0**
- IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.254.1
- IPv4 DNS Server: 192.168.254.1
- IPv4 WINS Server:
- NetBIOS over Tcpip Enabled: Yes
- Link-local IPv6 Address: fe80::3dbd:694d:2c37:f36d%12
- IPv6 Default Gateway:
- IPv6 DNS Server:

When should look like this:

- Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
- Description: Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
- Physical Address: 00-15-5D-FE-0C-01
- DHCP Enabled: No
- **Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 192.168.254.30**
- **IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0**
- IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.254.1
- IPv4 DNS Server: 192.168.254.1
- IPv4 WINS Server:
- NetBIOS over Tcpip Enabled: Yes
- Link-local IPv6 Address: fe80::3dbd:694d:2c37:f36d%12
- IPv6 Default Gateway:
- IPv6 DNS Server:

Any help is welcome

Comment: Double check that the IP address you're assigning (192.168.254.30) isn't already in use. Sometimes an IP clash on the network can cause these symptoms.

Comment: Is there an actual problem or is this just cosmetic?

Comment: It's a real problem.

Comment: Graham Wager, thanks for the help, somehow the DHCP server was assigning adresses from a exclusion range, now everything is OK