# Port forwarding with Hyper-V virtual machine on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu 18.04 in a Hyper-V virtual machine on Windows 10 and I need to make its port 51235 to be accessible from the internet.

There are various related posts, for example:

1. [Hyper-V and a static IP address for Ubuntu VM](https://superuser.com/questions/1365849/hyper-v-and-a-static-ip-address-for-ubuntu-vm)
2. [Hyper-V VM Static IP - 2 IP Addresses](https://superuser.com/questions/516380/hyper-v-vm-static-ip-2-ip-addresses)
3. [Make dynamic IP address fixed?](https://superuser.com/questions/211955/make-dynamic-ip-address-fixed)

But it is still not clear enough. Should I configure my `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch)`, which my virtual machine is connected to, or should I create a new specific network adapter?

How to enable NAT? And what is value my static IP address?

What is the easiest way to configure Ubuntu to make it have static (fixed) IP address?

Below I've provided the list of my network adapters obtained with `ipconfig /all` command:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-L5J499D
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-00-68-05
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34b5:c9a0:8af:f4d2%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.80.80(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 637539677
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-33-5B-4C-B0-6E-BF-C0-EE-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Microsoft Emulator NAT Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-00-68-06
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d4d9:73c7:599c:f657%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.80.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 738202973
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-33-5B-4C-B0-6E-BF-C0-EE-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B0-6E-BF-C0-EE-1C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e015:e896:a9c:5ef3%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.104(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, June 5, 2019 4:38:09 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, June 5, 2019 10:38:08 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 61894335
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-33-5B-4C-B0-6E-BF-C0-EE-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-01-1A-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::502b:1b91:2c6:5a6a%27(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.244.65(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 452990301
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-33-5B-4C-B0-6E-BF-C0-EE-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**EDIT1:**

With the dynamic IP address on Ubuntu I have this:

```
$ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group defaul                          t qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group defa                          ult qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:00:68:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.103/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute e                          th0
       valid_lft 5759sec preferred_lft 5759sec
    inet6 fe80::6476:961e:3158:86f5/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

on Windows side:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34b5:c9a0:8af:f4d2%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.80.80
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Microsoft Emulator NAT Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d4d9:73c7:599c:f657%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.80.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (External Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b453:fe72:12d3:5982%37
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.104
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::502b:1b91:2c6:5a6a%27
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.244.65
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I tried the following Ubuntu settings, but they breaks the internet connection:

[image: Ubuntu Wired Network Settings]

**EDIT2:**

My external virtual switch is configured as follows:

[image: Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager]

`Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V` is my network card listed in Device Manager. My external virtual switch is selected as the network adapter for my virtual machine:

[image: Hyper-V Virtual Machine Network Settings]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hyper-V Network Adapter**:  You want to set up an external virtual switch in Hyper-V, if you haven't already and assign that to your VM.  This will allow your VM access to your host's network.  You don't want to use the default NAT adapter with Hyper-V, it's not configurable and doesn't allow port forwarding.

To set up an external virtual switch:
In Hyper-V Manager, click **Virtual Switch Manager**, select **External**, click **Create Virtual Switch**.  Under **External network**, select the network card that is connected to your network, **Allow management OS to share this network adapter** should remain checked. Click **OK**.  Assign this new virtual switch to the Ubuntu VM.   *Note: this will temporarily disconnect your host PC from the network while the virtual switch is installing.*

**NAT**:  You should already have NAT enabled on your firewall/router.  It's not a good idea to be directly connected to the internet.  You don't need NAT on your Windows 10 host for this to work, it will only add to the complexity.

**Static IP**:  You would pick this based on your network.  You should pick a value that's outside your DHCP scope, but in the same subnet (192.168.0.x).

**Port forwarding**:  Use the port forwarding on your router/firewall to handle the port forward.  Use an external virtual switch and assign your VM an IP from your regular network.  Configure the port forwarding for the Port/IP address in your router/firewall.

**Configure Ubuntu for static IP**: You do this in your VM, not in an Hyper-V component. In Ubuntu, go to Settings-->Network.  Click the gear icon next to the wired network connection. Click the IPv4 tab, click Manual, and enter the IP settings specific to your network.  The subnet mask, gateway, and DNS values should be the same as the host's.

See this link for pictures of above: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: I created external network adapter and the dynamic IP address of my Ubuntu machine is now 192.168.0.103, see EDIT1. What should I specify as Netmask and Gateway in Ubuntu Settings->Network->IP4 page? If I leave them empty the internet connection is lost.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know exactly what Netmask and Gateway are, I tried 255.255.255.0 and 192.168.0.1, but with no success. See the picture.

Comment: Those should be correct, netmask and gateway (and DNS) will be the same as the host as long as you're using an external virtual switch.  Verify that your external switch is connected to your active network card.

Comment: Where to check this?

Comment: Does it relate somehow to Network Adapter->Properties->Sharing?

Comment: No, you don't need to use adapter sharing.  Look in the Hyper-V Manager under Virtual Switch Manager. Click on the virtual switch you've created, you can't use the default switch for this, and verify that it's set to "external network" and your network card is listed there.  "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" should also be checked.

Comment: This is the virtual switch you want to assign to the VM: Ethernet adapter vEthernet (External Virtual Switch)

Comment: I added the screenshots of the switch configuration, see EDIT2. Are they OK?

Comment: That looks correct.  Does the Ubuntu VM get an IP from DHCP with that config?

Comment: If I set 'manual' in Ubuntu settings the IP address is 192.168.0.113, but there is no internet. With 'automatic' the IP address is 192.168.0.103 and the internet works fine.

Comment: After i add external switch i lost connection to Host by ip-address used by network adapter listed in that switch.

Answer (score 16):

After digging through the article linked to in Alexis Tupeck's answer, I was able to set up a Hyper-V Internal Switch, give it a new private IP/subnet, and create a new NAT on this subnet. Then I could set up VMs with static IPs on the subnet, and forward ports to them on the new NAT.

The following example will set up an internal network with the Hyper-V host on **172.16.10.254 /24**, and the guest VM on **172.16.10.100**.

##### **1**. Make a new Hyper-V Internal Switch

This can either be done through the Hyper-V Manager or through PowerShell:

```
New-VMSwitch  -SwitchName "NAT Switch"  -SwitchType Internal
```

This will create a new network adapter named "vEthernet (NAT Switch)", which we use below.

##### **2**. Set up a new IP address/subnet for the Hyper-V host on the new adapter

We will use **172.16.10.254** here, with a /24 subnet (255.255.255.0).

```
New-NetIPAddress  -IPAddress 172.16.10.254  -PrefixLength 24  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (NAT Switch)"
```

This new Hyper-V host IP will be the gateway for the VMs.

##### **3**. Set up a NAT Network on the new subnet:

```
New-NetNat  -Name NATNetwork  -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 172.16.10.0/24
```

This sets up Windows to perform network address translation on packets to/from this subnet.

##### **4**. Set up a VM on the virtual switch.

Give it a static IP of **172.16.10.100** - use /24 or 255.255.255.0 for the subnet mask - and set its gateway to the Hyper-V host on **172.16.10.254**.

(Assuming the Hyper-V host isn't serving DNS on your new subnet, you can likely just point its DNS servers to the same ones the host is using itself, or something external e.g. 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8.)

You should now be able to reach the Internet from the VM through the Hyper-V host using the NAT.

##### **5**. Set up a port-forward on the NAT Network to the VM (e.g. **TCP 1443** -> **172.16.10.100:443**):

```
Add-NetNatStaticMapping  -NatName NATNetwork  -Protocol TCP  -ExternalIPAddress 0.0.0.0/24  -ExternalPort 1443  -InternalIPAddress 172.16.10.100  -InternalPort 443
```

After this, you should be able to access the VM's port 443 through `localhost:1443` on the Hyper-V host.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a note, you CAN do static NAT mapping without putting your VM on your physical network, this allows you to use your host to be the only device on the phyiscal network while keeping your other VMs behind your host's firewall/segmented and share the same MAC as host which is often needed in universities, schools, dorms, etc.

https://petri.com/create-nat-rules-hyper-v-nat-virtual-switch